# How to read a part of a file

Tags: python, file

I have a file, and I want to print only the first paragraph in it.

This is my file:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
  Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore--
  While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
  As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
  "'Tis some visitor," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door--
                                     Only this and nothing more."

  Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December,
  And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.
  Eagerly I wished the morrow;--vainly I had sought to borrow
  From my books surcease of sorrow--sorrow for the lost Lenore--
  For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore--
                                     Nameless here for evermore.
```

How would I do this?

Comment: How do you open files in Python? How do you read files? What separates paragraphs? How do you split a string up by that delimiter?  Answer those questions for yourself first, then you will be armed to ask a good question. The title doesn't even accurately describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the file till you reach an empty line, like this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       if line == '':  # exit when you reach the end of the first paragraph
           break 
       print line
```

Comment: @jorrede please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful for you by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

you can split your file at the paragraphs and print any one of them like this:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    paragraphs = f.read().split('\n\n')
    print(paragraphs[0])
```